# Javascript not able to read a file that exists with read permissions enabled

Tags: javascript, macos

I am getting the following erorr

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/thorg/integ/creation_integ_tests/thorg.9e2f69c4-83e2-4994-9481-ddd2fe928841.json
```

When attempting to read a file synchronously (after a synchronous write within the same process in integration tests)

```
 fs.readFileSync(filePath);
```

From my understanding ENOENT is likely to do with permissions. However, the file has read permission for everyone `-rw-r--r--`

```
> stat /tmp/thorg/integ/creation_integ_tests/thorg.9e2f69c4-83e2-4994-9481-ddd2fe928841.json
16777220 85706805 -rw-r--r-- 1 vintrino wheel 0 232 "May 24 20:53:36 2021" "May 24 20:53:36 2021" "May 24 20:53:36 2021" "May 24 20:53:35 2021" 4096 8 0 /tmp/thorg/integ/creation_integ_tests/thorg.9e2f69c4-83e2-4994-9481-ddd2fe928841.json
```

Am I missing something with unix permissions here?

Comment: `ENOENT` has nothing to do with permissions; if it's a permission problem you get `EPERM`. `ENOENT` means exactly what the message says.

Comment: Did you close the file between writing it and trying to open it for reading?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You should tag this `nodejs`